# SDL - Move cursor with rect x and y smaller than zero

Tags: cursor, mouse, sdl, rect

I implemented a custom cursor on my SDL game. When moving it across the screen I can go as far as I want to the right and to the bottom. But the cursor will not go beyond the ledt or the top wall. I'm using `SDL_GetMouseState` and passing the current `x` and `y` values to it.

How do I manage to allow a surface to move to the position `(-5, 0)`?

**Here's some code:**

```
typedef struct {
    SDL_Surface *image;
    SDL_Rect frame;
} Cursor;



void moveCursor(Cursor *cursor) {

    Sint16 *x = &cursor->frame.x;
    Sint16 *y = &cursor->frame.y;

    Uint16 cursorWidth = cursor->frame.w;
    Uint16 cursorHeight = cursor->frame.h;

    SDL_GetMouseState((int *)x, (int *)y); 

    cursor->frame.w = cursorWidth;
    cursor->frame.h = cursorHeight;

    SDL_Rect temporaryFrame = cursor->frame;

    SDL_BlitSurface(cursor->image, NULL, bufferSurface.surface, &temporaryFrame);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't copy the last line to the editor when I created the post.

Comment: Just blit it with an negative offset regarding the video surface.

Comment: SDL will automatically turn my negative coordinate into 0.

Comment: SDL_Rect is using signed variables so negative coordinates are possible. Obviously there is a problem with your code, which you have not shown.

Comment: Sorry again. I just updated my question with the code I'm using :)

Comment: Apparently SDL doesn't detect mouse movement outside the window. Your solution is pretty simple. Keep the real mouse always positioned at the center of the window and only record relative motions of it. Then display your "fake" mouse wherever you want.

Comment: Great idea! And it's pretty simple. Sometimes we make simple things so complex. Sometimes all we need is [Jeff Atwood's rubber duck](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html). Would you be so kind as to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDL doesn't detect mouse movements outside its window, so you cannot have negative mouse coordinates.

To simulate a mouse that can move offscreen, always keep the mouse centered and store it's relative motion. The relative motion is translated to your virtual mouse that can now move anywhere and is represented by a sprite.